# How does numPy's advanced indexing work for boolean masks?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, syntax

I am very new to Python, and I am struggling with understanding how the following code works.

I have an image read into a numpy array. Similar to this:

`# Read the image
image = mpimg.imread('images/rgb-road.png')`

After this I set a 3-value boundary list rgb_boundary[123,231,122]. The values are irrelevant.

Then comes the confusing part.

```
boundary = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_boundary[0]) \
            | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1]) \
            | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
image[boundary] = [0,0,0]
```

It is the combination of my poor knowledge of Python syntax and working with images that is causing the issue.

I would be extremely happy if somebody could explain what is happening in the above piece of code. Especially in the line where we have the image[boundary] assignment. My image values are changed, but I don't understand how this is working in Python.

In addition, if there is a resource where I can read about how/why this is working, please feel free to refer me to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the first piece that executes:

```
image[:,:,0] < rgb_boundary[0]
```

Now, `rgb_boundary[0]` is simply `123`, so what this does is find the locations where the first color (red) in the image is less than 123 intensity (so about half-bright, since 255 is max-bright).

The result of the above expression will be a 2D boolean array, which is True wherever the red color byte is less than 123, and False elsewhere.

We can then understand this code:

```
boundary = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_boundary[0]) \
         | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_boundary[1]) \
         | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_boundary[2])
```

It is creating a 2D mask called `boundary` which will be `True` for any pixel where red is less than 123, or green is less than 231, or blue is less than 122.  It will be `False` wherever none of those conditions are met.

Finally:

```
image[boundary] = [0,0,0]
```

This sets the selected pixels to black.  In NumPy, a boolean mask like `boundary` can be used with "fancy [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)" to create a "view" of an array.  In this case, the "view" is used to assign `[0,0,0]` (black) to `image` wherever the `boundary` condition is `True`.